# The different with methods

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to understand what is the difference when you are passing and argument or no argument in a method.

I think I kind of understand. Would it be if you was to pass an argument it would be something like this.

```
int numA = 4;

int productA =  squar(numA);
```

I just don't understand how to have a method where it is not passing an argument.

Comment: If you tell us what programming language you're familiar with, we can tell you what the differences are between it and C#. The way your question is worded now, it sounds like you're new to programming entirely.

Comment: Yes I am new to the program and learning. I am new to C# I know somethings but very little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, and there are some "advanced" features of C# which can come into play, but in *simple* C#, when you call a method each *argument* (in the calling code) has to correspond with a *parameter* in the method declaration. You can declare methods with several parameters, just one, or none:

```
public void Foo() // No parameters
{
    Console.WriteLine("Foo!");
}

public void Bar(int x) // One parameter
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bar!");
}

public void Baz(int x, string y) // Two parameters
{
    Console.WriteLine("Baz!");
}
```

And then calling them:

```
Foo(); // No arguments
Bar(10); // One argument
Baz(20, "second"); // Two arguments
```

The *types* of the arguments have to be compatible with the types of the parameters in the corresponding method declaration.

Comment: Ok so the arguments are inside the () so If you don't want to pass an Arugement all you would have is this() and not this(time).

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use same method with parameters and without parameters, you have to write method overload for that. it is not a concept of c#, it's a part of object oriented programming.

```
    public string Test() // No parameters
    {
        return "test method";
    }

    public string Test(string testParam) // with parameters
    {
        return "test method with parameter " + testParam;
    }
```

so you can call,

```
Test();

Test("string parameter");
```

result,

```
test method
test method with parameter string parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 4.0 and above there is a new feature called optional parameters.

Lets say you have a method signature like this

```
static void Method(int value = 1, string name = "Perl")
{
     Console.WriteLine("value = {0}, name = {1}", value, name);
}


    Method(); //prints 1, Perl


    Method(4);//prints 4, perl


    Method("Dot"); // prints 1, Dot


    Method(4, "Dot"); //prints 4, Dot
```